# Error [I18N] Hardcoded string en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

No fue hasta hace poco que aprendí en Java lo necesario para programar aplicaciones en android y soy prácticamente un novato en esta tecnología, me ayudaría mucho si me ayudaran con este mensaje de advertencia:

> Message: [I18N] Hardcoded string "Me agrada programar en Java!", should use `@string` resource
>
> Suggested Fixes:
>
> - Extract string resource
>
> - Suppress: Add tools:ignore="HardcodedText" attribute
>
> Priority: 5 / 10
>
> Category: Internationalization
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Explanation: Hardcoded text. Hardcoding text attributes directly in layout files is bad for several reasons:
>
> - When creating configuration variations (for example for landscape or portrait)you have to repeat the actual text (and keep it up to date when making changes)
> - The application cannot be translated to other languages by just adding new translations for existing string resources.  There are quickfixes to automatically extract this hardcoded string into a resource lookup.

Comment: Deberías añadir el fragmento de código donde te aparece este aviso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En realidad no es un error, sino una advertencia (Warning):

> Severity: Warning ...

Te está diciendo que no es una buena práctica poner en tus layouts (archivos XML) cadenas escritas a mano.

La práctica recomendada es usar los recursos string para declarar allí tus cadenas.

En la ruta del proyecto tienes este archivo: `res/values/strings.xml` 
en el cual Android recomienda que declares tus strings.

Se parece a esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="appName">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="otraCadena">Cualquier cosa</string>
</resources>
```

Si luego quieres usar cualquier cadena en un elemento de un layout, supongamos un TextView:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/otraCadena" />
```

Y si quieres usar `otraCadena` en 200 partes de tu App, lo harías del mismo modo:

`... android:text="@string/otraCadena" />`

**¿Qué utilidad tiene eso?**

Supongamos que resulta que hay un error en `otraCadena` o hay cambiarla por `estaOtraCadena`, **sólo cambias el valor una sola vez en `strings.xml`** y se actualiza en todas partes. ¿O prefieres buscarlo y cambiarlo 200 veces?

Por eso Android te advierte de que no es una buena idea lo que estás intentando hacer.

También, el mismo mensaje de error te dice algunos motivos por los que esta práctica no es recomendable:

- Al crear variaciones de configuración (por ejemplo, para paisaje o retrato), debe repetir el texto real (y mantenerlo al día al realizar cambios)
- La aplicación no se puede traducir a otros idiomas simplemente añadiendo nuevas traducciones para recursos de cadenas existentes. Hay correcciones rápidas para extraer automáticamente esta cadena codificada en una búsqueda de recursos.

**Con otros elementos, no sólo con las cadenas**

Esta práctica es recomendada no sólo con las cadenas, sino con otros elementos como los colores, los estilos, las dimensiones, las imágenes ... en fin, todo lo que hay en la carpeta `res/values/...` de cualquier proyecto Android.

Si abres por el ejemplo el archivo `colors.xml` podrás ver algo como esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
</resources>
```

Puedes usar esos recursos combinados con `styles.xml` para aplicar estilos y colores a los elementos del layout:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Si quieres cambiar el color de cualquier elemento, sólo cambias su valor en `colors.xml`, sin tener que preocuparte de buscar en el código o en los layouts, cada vez que ese color aparece.

Como ves, la carpeta `res`, es muyyyy interesante y te ahorra muchísimo trabajo.

Comment: Gracias, aprecio mucho que te hayas tomado el tiempo para ayudarme con mis inquietudes.

Comment: De nada @CokóroR1 , me alegro de que te haya sido útil esta información.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por este aporte, la verdad me sirvió muchísimo.

Comment: Tu respuesta ha sido muy util, comenzando con A.S 3.3.2